# How to bind Dropdown from enums in mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, dropdown

How to bind dropdown from `enum` in mvc. 
The text data should be Data attribute display name.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
@Html.DropDownList("MyType", 
   EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(MyType)) , 
   "Select My Type", 
   new { @class = "form-control" })
```